# Drupal 7 access control for nodes/content

Tags: drupal

I installed Drupal 7 but the only access control option available is for viewing published content.  I want to be able to set different access control options for the different content I create.  Some pages should be viewable by some people and other pages shouldn't.

Drupal 6 has the Node Access module which is capable of this but it's not available in Drupal 7.  Are there any other options available?

Any help would be REALLY appreciated, I'm stuck!

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal there is Module knows **Protected Pages**. This Module has following Description

Protected Pages modules allows the administrator to secure any page in your website by password. You just need to go to configuration page of this module and add path, password. After that the added path will be password protected. This module also allows you to send the details of this protected page to multiple users by email.

This module allow administrator to set global password for all protected pages. This module provide bypass password protection of protected pages permission also. All the protected pages will be accessible by users having this permission.

This module is different from Protected Node module because this module allows password protection for all pages while "Protected Node" module only allows password protection for nodes.

https://www.drupal.org/project/protected_pages

Answer (score 0):

You want the privacy by node module. However, Drupal 7 isn't stable yet. You may want to consider rolling back to 6.